# Jenkins Maven Integration Plugin building all existing branches

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

We are using Jenkins with multi-branch pipelines and the Maven Integration plugin. I configured the multi-branch pipeline to "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built". When our dev branch was built, it seemed to build every branch of all dependent repos. How may we limit it to only build branch X when branch X is built?